# PHP 7.1 XML domDocument clone node with subnodes

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, php-7.1, clonenode

I have to solve this problem with PHP and DomDocument (also simplexml could be OK).
I've googled alot but not found a right example to learn how to do:

I have the following eBay XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>INSERT_TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <InventoryStatus>
    <ItemID> ItemIDType (string) </ItemID>
    <Quantity> int </Quantity>
    <SKU> SKUType (string) </SKU>
    <StartPrice> AmountType (double) </StartPrice>
  </InventoryStatus>
  <ErrorLanguage>en-US</ErrorLanguage>
  <Version> string </Version>
  <WarningLevel>Low</WarningLevel>
</ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
```

and I need to clone (actually 4 times) the `<InventoryStatus>` Node with all its subnodes:

```
  <InventoryStatus>
    <ItemID> ItemIDType (string) </ItemID>
    <Quantity> int </Quantity>
    <SKU> SKUType (string) </SKU>
    <StartPrice> AmountType (double) </StartPrice>
  </InventoryStatus>
```

and append just under the current Node

Can pls give some hints

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMDocument is much better at handling things like this and can just clone nodes with `cloneNode()`, passing `true` does a deep clone which will copy the content as well.  You can then add the node back in where you need it...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("data.xml");

$is = $dom->getElementsByTagName("InventoryStatus");
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($is[0]->cloneNode(true));
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($is[0]->cloneNode(true));
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($is[0]->cloneNode(true));
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($is[0]->cloneNode(true));
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: Wow! So simple :-(
OK, I've also been able to modify values for all the childnodes of all cloned Nodes, and to remove a node from dom and to use insertbefore
BUT not succeeded to remove a node from $is .. may I ask you also  this issue
Thanks

Comment: When you say remove a node, can you give an example of what you want to remove.

Comment: Quantity:
I did this but does not work:
`
      $Q = $is->getElementsByTagName("Quantity");
      $Q->parentNode->removeChild($Q);
`

Comment: `$is` is a DOMNodeList, if you want to use this, then as in the call to `cloneNode()` you need to use `$is[0]`

Comment: I see.. I made many tests and I'm sure I put [0] in many places.. and I'm sure also in that point.. but since I checked again.. in this case the error is in the latter instruction:  `$Q->parentNode->removeChild($Q); `

Comment: OK.. I will make some further tests.
Thanks a lot: now at least know that that instruction is correct!
Since I do not want to remove from $dom, but from the cloned $is
since some node will have Quantity and some other will have not.

as I removed another Node, but this time from $dom:
with these instructions: $SKU= $xml->getElementsByTagName("SKU")->item(0);   $SKU->parentNode->removeChild($SKU);